# jquery globalize: how to add the modules I need to the project

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-globalize

They examples and the code only mention in passing how to use only the modules you need.

For example, if you need the date formatter, how do you consume it?

Do you just munge it together in the same with globalize.js, or load it somehow separately, similar to loading the cldr files?

For example:

```
<html>
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
     </head> 
     ...
```

Loads globalize.js just fine. But I don't have the date module loaded, so
somewhere in the code Globalize.dateFormat is not defined.

but if I do this, to get the date module, as shown in one of the examples.

```
 <html>
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/globalize/date.js"></script>
     </head> 
     ...
```

Doesn't load globalize at all; if I try to do Globalize.locale("us") then Globalize is undefined.

Comment: Well, munging doesn't work. It then can't even find Globalize at all.

Comment: Loading separately doesn't work either.

Comment: hey - can you give an example of what you tried. I am not sure if you mean only including certain modules WITHIN the jquery library or how to include modules.. ie. ui/form validation etc..

Comment: I'm not working with the best debugger here, I'm remoting over usb cable. It seems like Globalize.load is not defined when I add the date.js to the scripts.

Comment: ok - well, it doesn't appear that you are using jQuery - which would make what I am about to say trivial. So, you try this. Load globalize.js -- since there is a global "Globalize" and that has a function "load". Create a setInterval for every 500ms to see if the object Globalize exists, and  if you want that Globalize.load exists and is a function. Then if they pass, create Script element and load date.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no need to do a delayed load of date.js, so I specified it in the header in the usual way. I did move it much further down, which may have given some of the prerequisites time to load.

```
var locLoaded = null;
function loadGlobalize(locale) {
  var loc = util.fixNoE(locale, "en");

  var codes = [
    'ar', 'ca', 'cs', 'da', 'de', 'el', 'en', 'en-001', 'en-AU', 'en-CA',
    'en-GB', 'en-HK', 'en-IN', 'es', 'fi', 'fr', 'he', 'hi', 'hr',
    'hu', 'it', 'ja', 'ko', 'nb', 'nl', 'pl', 'pt', 'pt-PT', 'ro', 'ru',
    'sk', 'sl', 'sr', 'sv', 'th', 'tr', 'uk', 'vi', 'zh', 'zh-Hant'
  ];

  if (codes.indexOf(loc) < 0) {
    var baseLoc = loc.split('-')[0];
    var index = codes.indexOf(baseLoc);
    loc = (index > -1 ? baseLoc : "EN");
  }

  if (loc != locLoaded) {

    var files = [
      "../globalize/supplemental/likelySubtags.json",
      "../globalize/supplemental/timeData.json",
      "../globalize/supplemental/weekData.json",
      "../globalize/main/" + loc + "/ca-gregorian.json",
      "../globalize/main/" + loc + "/numbers.json",
      "../globalize/main/" + loc + "/dateFields.json"
    ];

    var fileCount = files.length;
    files.forEach(function(f) {
      $.getJSON(f, function(data) {
        fileCount--;
        Globalize.load(data);
        if (fileCount == 0) {
          //wait until the last file is loaded to specify the locale
          Globalize.locale(loc);
        }
      });
    });
    locLoaded = loc;
  }
}

loadGlobalize(window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language);
```

In my app this code is in block where the DOM and jQuery are already loaded. There are two things that differ from the globalize.js documentation that caused this problem:

1. You have to do $.getJSON() instead of $.get() as specified in the documentation example.
2. If you run Globalize.locale() before the appropriate data files are loaded, you don't get a valid date formatter object.